# how to import a web application on a junit java project

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, mockito, junit4

i wrote few test cases using junit and mockito for a web application, while writing test cases , i gave dependency on build path as one other project which is a dynamic web application. now i have written all test cases using mocking and junit , but don't know how to give that web application as dependency to my junit project now when i have to deploy it , eclipse can have dependent project on build path it worked like that but how can we do that outside of any IDE , specially web application.

Thanks.

Comment: Please be more specific about your "web application", what is it? How do you run it? What are you trying to achieve? And above all: what did you try?

Comment: it's a Junit project trying to unit test a web application , both are different projects , in IDE i gave dependancy in build path which included my web application inside Junit application , so now i can run test on it , but it only works inside IDE , now when i am outside of IDE running that Junit test cases it can't find those Classes ( servlets) because i don't know how to put a .WAR in class path of a project.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186863/adding-wars-to-javas-classpath

Answer (score 1):

Run your tests inside your web project. Define another source package like '/src/test/' and put them there. Then modify your ant script:

- run these tests on build or test
- exclude this source package on war.

Alternative extract common classes, which both projects are using, and create a new project jar. Then import this new jar on both projects as dependency.

Comment: in this case there will not be any common classes , i am doing unit class to a test coverage of 90% , means i will be going to run test case on almost complete code. but yes making a jar out of web application using ant is one option.